# Why mobile applications share device characteristics with third parties?

Tags: mobile, data-leakage, third-party

It is known that mobile applications can share with third parties many different types of data from information about the device to search terms used in the application.

I understand that search terms are useful to businesses in order to achieve targeted advertising. However I cannot imagine how device information are useful to them.

If you could provide me with any literature that explain this I would be grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more information third parties have about a consumer the more accurately they can profile what causes a consumer to make decisions. Simply knowing what app's are on a mobile device can reveal a lot of demographic information about the user (think dating apps, news apps, religious apps, type of games purchased, etc). Likewise the type of hardware you are using can also imply economic information (using a $1200.00 phone vs. the most popular free phone given away with two-year plans). This type of information is worth a lot of money to a variety of organizations as it can help them persuade the consumer to do things (buy things, vote on things, change the way they view a political topic, etc.) What you are asking about is a HUGE subject and the data is used in millions or ways but the following to URLs would be a good place to get some background information on it.

http://www.cbsnews.com/news/the-data-brokers-selling-your-personal-information/

https://www.privacyrights.org/content/data-brokers-and-your-privacy

BTW: a popular book which covers this information and probably provides a much more in-depth answer to your question is

Data and Goliath: The Hidden Battles to Collect Your Data and Control Your World
by Bruce Schneier
ISBN-13: 978-0393352177
ISBN-10: 039335217X